# How do you refer to an entity of controversial labelling without cataphora?

Tags: syntactic-analysis, reference

Pretend that you are beginning to describe an as-of-yet unnamed thing, but there is more than one name for it. Have a toy-example sentence:

> That is the face all Redditors make when you call a majorly obese cat a majorly obese cat instead of a "chonker."

This sentence is clunky. One, there's the repetition of an already verbose noun phrase, and also, it gives greater weight to one name over another. There is a way to avoid this...:

> That is the face all Redditors make when you call **it** a "majorly obese cat" instead of a "chonker."

...but now there's a cataphora, which could temporarily disorient a reader in a non-toy context, especially when a subordinate clause separates "it" some distance from either of the names.

This might not be a single word I'm looking for; for example, take this example using circumlocution:

> Even city names can give you away. Calling **the city not so far from the northern part of the border of Northern Ireland** "Derry" or "Londonderry" shows what side you're on.

What's a more concise way? How do you give equal weight to "chonker" and "majorly obese cat," or "Derry" and "Londonderry," without cataphora?

Comment: Redditors like to call a majorly obese cat a “chonker” and will make faces if you don’t follow suit.

Comment: I don't know if that was a joking response, but that assigns even more weight to "majorly obese cat."

Comment: The first thing you do is to delete the word 'majorly'.  Are there in this game two or three degrees of girth?  And with the Londonderry example, why not think of a better example?  At least, I would need to see the problem that led to the sentence.  You might (I am guessing) try:  "In some towns people will decide whether you are Republican or Unionist according to whether you use the name Derry or Londonderry."  It is no longer (2 words shorter, in fact, and less stilted.